# Laravel - Artisan::call() doesn't take argument

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and PHP 7.0.

I have a lot of failed jobs in the table that I want to re-queue. I have written a script to go through a list of IDs that I pulled from the database and I want a foreach to re-queue each one. Pretty simple stuff.

My issue is that when I run

```
foreach($jobsToRetry as $failedJob) {
    Artisan::call('queue:retry '.$failedJob);
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
Command "queue:retry 1" is not defined.

Did you mean one of these?
    queue:failed
    queue:failed-table
    queue:flush
    queue:forget
    queue:listen
    queue:restart
    queue:retry
    queue:table
    queue:work
```

It needs to be using the command "queue:retry" and have the parameter separate but I just can't figure out how to get that to work.

Comment: Please write your full command like (i.e php artisan queue:retry --failed=1)

Comment: Or give example of your command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the parameter in the arguments

`Artisan::call('queue:retry', ['id' => $failedJob]);`

Comment: Is 'id' the correct parameter name? If so thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
Artisan::call('queue:retry', ['--yourparameter' => $failedJob]);
```

Comment: `--yourparameter` won't work. `id` is a required argument, not [optional](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan#defining-input-expectations)